# Django: 'no such table' after extending the User model using OneToOneField

Tags: django

(Django 1.10.) I'm trying to follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) advice on extending the user model using OneToOneField. In my app 'polls' (yes, I'm extending the app made in the 'official' tutorial) I want to store two additional pieces of information about each user, namely, a string of characters and a number.

In my models.py I now have the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stopien = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pensum = models.IntegerField()
```

and in admin.py the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from polls.models import Employee

class EmployeeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'employee'

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (EmployeeInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

When adding a user using the admin panel my two new fields display correctly. However, when I click 'save', or if I don't add any user and just click on the name of my sole admin user in the admin panel, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/1/change/
no such table: polls_employee
```

I see some questions and answers related to similar problems, but they seem to be relevant for older version of Django. Could anyone give me a tip as to what I should do? Ideally I'd want my two additional fields display in the admin panel, though I suspect this might be a task for the future.

I have to confess I do not understand this paragraph from the documentation just following the advice I'm using:

*These profile models are not special in any way - they are just Django      models that happen to have a one-to-one link with a User model. As such, they do not get auto created when a user is created, but a **django.db.models.signals.post_save** could be used to create or update related models as appropriate.*

Do I need to tie this 'post-save' to some element of the admin panel?

I'd be very greatful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need run `makemigrations` to create a migration for your new model, and then `migrate` to run the migration and create the database table.

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```